# Como solucionar mi pantalla en ubuntu, pareciera que hubiera un zoom contrario

Tags: ubuntu

Tengo un problema con el tamaño de las ventanas en el sistema operativo de Ubuntu, tengo una resolucion de pantalla de 1920 X 1080, el  texto es muy pequeño intente poner zoom en la ventana de chrome pero el problema va que es muy incomodo y este problema me afecto tambien en Postman

[image: imagen de ubuntu en chrome]

Comment: cabe recalcar que reduci el tamaño de la resolucion pero se perdio calidad de imagen

Comment: system settings -> accesibility -> seeing -> font scaling